# React cannot detect 'delete key' in my KeyDown event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, keypress

I have been trying for days to capture a 'delete' key press in React. My function is always evaluating to false. why?

```
          <textarea
            className="DetailsPage-txt-area"
            placeholder="Write a short bio about yourself..."
            value={bio}
            onChange={handleSetBio}
            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}
          ></textarea>
```

```
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 46) {
      console.log('true');
    } else {
      console.log('false')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`46` is `keyCode` of `Delete`. But I think you press `backspace` with `keyCode` is `8`. So just update to handle 2 case.

```
if (e.keyCode === 46 || e.keyCode === 8) {
  console.log('true');
} else {
  console.log('false')
}
```